# how to fetch data from one class to another in orientdb

Tags: database, mongoose, orientdb, graph-databases

I have created two classes **customer** and **city**. 
**customer** class contain two properties *name* and *location* and **city** class contain *id* and *location* .
I want to perform join operations on these two classes.
I create a graph relation in orientdb studio and fire a query below

```
select from customer where city.location='pune'
```

but this query not returning any value,it executed but not returning any field,
So, this is correct syntax or i am doing wrong in somewhere ..
please give me solutions.

Comment: What is the type of the field "location" ?

Comment: The class "customer" doesn't have the field "city", you have declared the fields "name" and "location"

Comment: hi, could you post the complete schema including vertex classes and edge classes?

Comment: the type of field location is string.

Comment: hi Ivan, here is complete schema ... i have taken two vertex customer and city. in customer class there is two properties name and city and in city two properties id and location................ and i have created  edges  LivesAt. i show the graph relation like 'suresh LivesAt pune' ....

Comment: hi Alessandro  i also taken field city in customer class and fire above same query. the query is exicuted but not return any result or recorts..   so, please give any solution

Comment: @suresh, as you can see from the answer of LucaS you can use "select from Customer where out('livesAt').location contains 'Pune' "

Comment: thanks Alessandro i got the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this simple dataset to give you some examples:

```
create class Customer extends V
create class City extends V
create class livesAt extends E

create property Customer.name String
create property City.id integer
create property City.location String

create vertex Customer set name="Tom"
create vertex Customer set name="John"
create vertex City set id=1, location="London"
create vertex City set id=2, location="Pune"

create edge livesAt from (select from Customer where name="Tom") to (select from City where id=1)
create edge livesAt from (select from Customer where name="John") to (select from City where id=2)
```

Now you can use different queries to retrieve the results you're looking for.

---

**Query 1a**: Starting from Customer (like your query above)

```
select from Customer where out('livesAt').location in 'Pune'
```

**Output**:

```
----+-----+--------+----+-----------
#   |@RID |@CLASS  |name|out_livesAt
----+-----+--------+----+-----------
0   |#12:1|Customer|John|[size=1]
----+-----+--------+----+-----------
```

---

**Query 1b**: Starting again from Customer

```
select from Customer where out('livesAt').location contains 'Pune'
```

**Output**:

```
----+-----+--------+----+-----------
#   |@RID |@CLASS  |name|out_livesAt
----+-----+--------+----+-----------
0   |#12:1|Customer|John|[size=1]
----+-----+--------+----+-----------
```

---

**Query 1c**:

```
select from Customer where out('livesAt')[location = 'Pune'].size() > 0
```

**Output**:

```
----+-----+--------+----+-----------
#   |@RID |@CLASS  |name|out_livesAt
----+-----+--------+----+-----------
0   |#12:1|Customer|John|[size=1]
----+-----+--------+----+-----------
```

---

**Query 2**: Starting from City (**more direct**)

```
select expand(in('livesAt')) from City where location = 'Pune'
```

**Output**:

```
----+-----+--------+----+-----------
#   |@RID |@CLASS  |name|out_livesAt
----+-----+--------+----+-----------
0   |#12:1|Customer|John|[size=1]
----+-----+--------+----+-----------
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi suresh, glad to have been helpful. If you believe that this is the correct answer, could you mark it as such ?